# Why is const required for a container

Tags: c++, for-loop, stl

Why do I get a C2440 for the

```
for(box& b : uset)
```

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const box' to 'box &'
>
> Error (active)    E0433   qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type
>   "box &" to initializer of type "const box"

```
class box
{
public:
    int i = 1;
    bool operator==(const box& other) const
    {
        return true;
    }
    bool operator!=(const box& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

};

namespace std {

    template<>
    struct hash<box>
    {
        size_t operator()(const box& boxObject) const
        {
            return boxObject.i;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<box> uset;
    for (box& b : uset)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused as if I make it a reference to `const box` then the problem goes away. If I swap `unordered_set` to a `vector` then it's not a problem. I'm not sure what is going on here. Can someone help explain it to me. Is this particular to associative containers? I see it also happen with `std::set`.

Comment: You can't modify elements in sets (only insert and remove them). Dereferencing set iterators gives you `const` objects.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's an answer, not a comment (IMHO).

Comment: What @Holy said is right. This is because mutating the elements could mess up their order/hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the associative containers only provide `const` access to the key type so you can't change it and break the way the container access the elements.  That means

```
decltype(*std::unordered_set<box>{}.begin())
```

gives you a `const box&`.  You can't bind a non const reference to a const object as that would violate const correctness so the code fails to compile.

What you need is

```
for (box const& b : uset)
{

}
```

so you have a reference to a `const box`.

You don't have this problem with a vector since the vector does not care about the value of the elements.  It access by index, not the value of a element so nothing can break by changing the value of the element.